# RSA Decryption Issue .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I got `Bad Key` Error when trying to decrypt with Private key. Encrypted content encrypted with my public key. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Error Occurred: Bad Key.

The below are my code:

```
Public Function RSADecryptCer(ByVal encryptedString As Byte()) As Byte()
    Try

        Dim cert As New X509Certificate2("E:\certificate.pfx", "12345", X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet)

        Dim rsa As RSACryptoServiceProvider = DirectCast(cert.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)

        Dim decrypted As Byte() = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedString, False)

        Return decrypted

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim str As String = ex.Message.ToString
    End Try

End Function
```